cisco ap access point air-cap 2700, how to upgrade firmware, need an expert
:-)
I got Cisco AP Air-Cap 2702I-E-K9 for free but they didn't get me password for this device. Now, when I hold the device reset button I get this message

Does anyone know what I need to do next to get the device working? I type enable command and hit enter but system said the command is not recognized. I hit dir command and system list next lines
flash (read-write)
xmodem (read-only)
null (read-write)
tftp (read-only)

How can I reset this device? I downloaded new firmware from cisco site. I installed tftpd64 and putty on my computer. I also connected cisco device with my pc through console port as you can see from image. But what next?


Here is the procedure:

Disconnect power from the AP or Disconnect the power jack for external power or the Ethernet cable for inline power.

Press and hold the MODE button while you reconnect power to the AP.

Hold the MODE button until the Status LED turns amber, and then release the button.

The Status LED turns amber in approximately 1 to 2 seconds.

After the AP reboots, reconfigure the AP


More info, check here:
http://blogs.scansource.com/cisco-ap1260-access-point-how-to-reset-defaults/
https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/wireless/access_point/12-4_21a_JA1/configuration/guide/scg12421aJA1/scg12421aJA1-chap4-first.html

https://community.cisco.com/t5/wireless/how-to-reset-cisco-air-cap-27021-f-k9/td-p/3308946

Hi Zac67
I successfully done the steps to reset the device but I don't know how to configure it further as I have never worked with cisco ap device before.
1st and 2nd link that you gave me doesn't work.
When I type

clear capwap ap all

it turns

Invalid input detected at ...

Does anyone know how to configure Cisco AP device after it was successfully reseted?

I guess your first question is answered then. Please don't forget to eventually accept an answer. (And you may vote for any useful ones, too.) Your new question from your comment means you need to read the manual. You can ask specific questions here, but we're not a how-to site.
